# iterating over a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, iteration

I am trying to change every element of a matrix, but my iteration doesn't work. The correct elements get overwritten with the last ones, but i don't know how to solve this.

I can't explain it very well, so below is my code to make things clear.
'return_matrix' should contain the elements made in the list 'perms' (in the same order).

The problem situates itself in the last part of the code, from where 'counter' is defined.

The desired output should be like the following, but in a 20x20 matrix.

```
['AA', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AP',
 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AV', 'AW', 'AY', 'CA', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'CG',
 'CH', 'CI', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CP', 'CQ', 'CR', 'CS', 'CT', 'CV', 'CW',
 'CY', 'DA', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DF', 'DG', 'DH', 'DI', 'DK', 'DL', 'DM', 'DN',
 'DP', 'DQ', 'DR', 'DS', 'DT', 'DV', 'DW', 'DY', 'EA', 'EC', 'ED', 'EE', 'EF',
 'EG', 'EH', 'EI', 'EK', 'EL', 'EM', 'EN', 'EP', 'EQ', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'EV',
 'EW', 'EY', 'FA', 'FC', 'FD', 'FE', 'FF', 'FG', 'FH', 'FI', 'FK', 'FL', 'FM',
 'FN', 'FP', 'FQ', 'FR', 'FS', 'FT', 'FV', 'FW', 'FY', 'GA', 'GC', 'GD', 'GE',
 'GF', 'GG', 'GH', 'GI', 'GK', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GS', 'GT',
 'GV', 'GW', 'GY', 'HA', 'HC', 'HD', 'HE', 'HF', 'HG', 'HH', 'HI', 'HK', 'HL',
 'HM', 'HN', 'HP', 'HQ', 'HR', 'HS', 'HT', 'HV', 'HW', 'HY', 'IA', 'IC', 'ID',
 'IE', 'IF', 'IG', 'IH', 'II', 'IK', 'IL', 'IM', 'IN', 'IP', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IS',
 'IT', 'IV', 'IW', 'IY', 'KA', 'KC', 'KD', 'KE', 'KF', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KK',
 'KL', 'KM', 'KN', 'KP', 'KQ', 'KR', 'KS', 'KT', 'KV', 'KW', 'KY', 'LA', 'LC',
 'LD', 'LE', 'LF', 'LG', 'LH', 'LI', 'LK', 'LL', 'LM', 'LN', 'LP', 'LQ', 'LR',
 'LS', 'LT', 'LV', 'LW', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MF', 'MG', 'MH', 'MI',
 'MK', 'ML', 'MM', 'MN', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MT', 'MV', 'MW', 'MY', 'NA',
 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NF', 'NG', 'NH', 'NI', 'NK', 'NL', 'NM', 'NN', 'NP', 'NQ',
 'NR', 'NS', 'NT', 'NV', 'NW', 'NY', 'PA', 'PC', 'PD', 'PE', 'PF', 'PG', 'PH',
 'PI', 'PK', 'PL', 'PM', 'PN', 'PP', 'PQ', 'PR', 'PS', 'PT', 'PV', 'PW', 'PY',
 'QA', 'QC', 'QD', 'QE', 'QF', 'QG', 'QH', 'QI', 'QK', 'QL', 'QM', 'QN', 'QP',
 'QQ', 'QR', 'QS', 'QT', 'QV', 'QW', 'QY', 'RA', 'RC', 'RD', 'RE', 'RF', 'RG',
 'RH', 'RI', 'RK', 'RL', 'RM', 'RN', 'RP', 'RQ', 'RR', 'RS', 'RT', 'RV', 'RW',
 'RY', 'SA', 'SC', 'SD', 'SE', 'SF', 'SG', 'SH', 'SI', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN',
 'SP', 'SQ', 'SR', 'SS', 'ST', 'SV', 'SW', 'SY', 'TA', 'TC', 'TD', 'TE', 'TF',
 'TG', 'TH', 'TI', 'TK', 'TL', 'TM', 'TN', 'TP', 'TQ', 'TR', 'TS', 'TT', 'TV',
 'TW', 'TY', 'VA', 'VC', 'VD', 'VE', 'VF', 'VG', 'VH', 'VI', 'VK', 'VL', 'VM',
 'VN', 'VP', 'VQ', 'VR', 'VS', 'VT', 'VV', 'VW', 'VY', 'WA', 'WC', 'WD', 'WE',
 'WF', 'WG', 'WH', 'WI', 'WK', 'WL', 'WM', 'WN', 'WP', 'WQ', 'WR', 'WS', 'WT',
 'WV', 'WW', 'WY', 'YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL',
 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY']
```

The output i get now is

```
[['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY'],
['YA', 'YC', 'YD', 'YE', 'YF', 'YG', 'YH', 'YI', 'YK', 'YL', 'YM', 'YN', 'YP', 'YQ', 'YR', 'YS', 'YT', 'YV', 'YW', 'YY']]
```

This is my code:

```
prot_alpha = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'

def listToString(s):   
    str1 = ""
    for ele in s:  
        str1 += ele   
    return str1 

perms = []
return_matrix = [[0]* len(prot_alpha)]* len(prot_alpha)

perm_list = itertools.product(prot_alpha, repeat=2)
for perm in perm_list:
    perms.append(listToString(perm))

counter = 0
for i in range(len(return_matrix)): 
        for j in range(len(return_matrix[i])):
                return_matrix[i][j] = perms[counter]
                counter += 1
print(perms)             
print(return_matrix)
```

Comment: What is the input? What did you expect as output? What do you get instead?

Comment: ``[[0]* len(prot_alpha)]* len(prot_alpha)`` does not duplicate the nested list, it merely creates new references to it.

Comment: In your question, try to explain in words what you are trying to do. It helps us and you when you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at your code too closely, I'd wager your problem stems from this line:

```
return_matrix = [[0]* len(prot_alpha)]* len(prot_alpha)
```

This creates a list of list-references, all of which are referring to the same list in memory. The result is that any change commited to ANY of the list-references will be reflected in all the other list-references as well, because what you're really doing is modifying the underlying list - the list-references are just windows to that single list.

For example:

```
>>> matrix = [[0] * 3] * 3
>>> matrix
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> matrix[0][0] = 1
>>> matrix
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

You'll want to avoid initializing your `return_matrix` in this way. Use a list-comprehension instead.

Comment: Problem identified. - How is the problem solved?

Comment: i found this online, and it does the job:
return_matrix = [[0]*20 for _ in range(20)]